# Equivalence Between Matrix Norms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have two symmetric positive semi-definite matrices $S$ and $E$. From my experiments, I found that the following proposition is (or might be) true. But I do not know how to strictly prove. I need to know the mathematical relation between $\rho$ and $\alpha$. $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the F norm or the spectral norm. Many thanks.

**Proposition**: If $\forall \rho \ge 0$, s.t.

$$
\sqrt{\text{Tr}[S+E-2(E^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot S \cdot E^{\frac{1}{2}})^{\frac{1}{2}}]} \le \rho ~~~~~~~(\text{note: the left-hand-side is also a norm proved to satisfy the norm axioms})
$$

then, $\exists \alpha \ge 0$, s.t.,

$$
\|S-E\| \le \alpha.
$$

Comment: What is meant by $\forall \rho\ge0, \sqrt{\cdots}\le \rho$ ? Should it mean that the expression is bounded? Also, there is always such an $\alpha$: $\|S-E\|\le\alpha:=\|S\|+\|E\|$.

Comment: @Chrystomath   Yes, good observation. The expression is bounded by $\rho$.
But as I mentioned in the beginning, I meant to find the relation between $\alpha$ and $\rho$. That is, I want to find a tight upper bound of $\|S-E\|$. As we can expect, $\alpha$ is a function of $\rho$.

Comment: So what you would like is some inequality like $\|S-E\|\le c\sqrt{\cdots}$ ? (or, more likely, the opposite $\ge$) You should change the question if this is so.